# It this probability measure correctly defined?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

I'm doing this problem for the part Information Theory in the class of Mathematical Statistics:

> [image]

IMHO, $f_{p, q}(x)=(1-p) p^{k} = (1-p)p^{x-q}$ for all $x \in \mathbb N$. Because $\forall x \in \mathbb N, \exists k \in \mathbb Z:x=q+k$, I could not understand how it's possible that $f_{p, q}(x)=0$.

Could you please elaborate on how this probability law is defined? Thank you so much!

Comment: I think it should be "k *non-negative* integer" in the definition. Otherwise, the total mass of $\mathbb{N}$ wouldn't even be $1$.

Comment: Thank you @Thorgott! I got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's from @Thorgot's comment that

> I think it should be "$k$ non-negative integer" in the definition. Otherwise, the total mass of $\mathbb N$ wouldn't even be $1$.

I post it as an answer to peacefully close this question.